# how to group date data in query MS sql server

Tags: sql-server

data like this below:

## TABLE 1

## Code         Date       type    TIME

code1         3/2/2021   P      08:00

code1   3/2/2021    P   16:00

ABC1    3/3/2021    P   08:00

ABC1    3/3/2021    P   16:00

code2   3/2/2021    S   15:00

code2   3/2/2021    S   23:00

code3   3/3/2021    S   15:00

code3   3/3/2021    S   23:00

cod34   3/10/2021   M   16:00

cod34   3/11/2021   M   07:01

cod34   3/12/2021   M   16:00

cod34   3/13/2021   M   07:15

## TABEL 2

## CODE    Date        IN  OUT

code1   3/2/2021    08:00   16:00

ABC1    3/3/2021    08:00   16:00

code2   3/2/2021    15:00   23:00

code3   3/3/2021    15:00   23:00

cod34   3/10/2021   16:00   07:01

cod34   3/12/2021   16:00   07:15

i have table database like table 1, so i want display like table 2. how to make it query in mssql server
at code34 time out to display next date

Comment: what kind of time format is P, S, M?

Comment: And what happens when "out" crosses a date boundary?

Comment: P = is AM to PM like this 08.00AM to 16:00PM, 
S = is PM to PM like this 15.00PM to 23:00PM, 
M = is PM to AM like this 16.00PM to 07:00AM  --> 07:00 AM is time out get time form date next

Comment: thas is data attendand, date "cross" is date and time out is AM, example IN date 3/2/2021 18:00 PM, and Out date 3/3/2021 07.00 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility :

```
SELECT Code, Date, Letter, MAX(Time),
       (SELECT MIN(Time) 
        FROM   Table AS T2 
        WHERE T1 .Code = T2.Code AND T1.date = T2.Date AND T1.letter = T2.letter)
FROM Table AS T1
GROUP  BY Code, Date, Letter;
```